# protothread jump a thread to the beginning in the external main function

Tags: protothread

I have a protothread set up and blocking ...

```
static int mythread(struct pt *pt){
  static int k;
  PT_BEGIN(pt)
  while(1){
     PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, eventA == 1);  // blocked at lineA

     for(k=0;k<100;k++){
        //do something
        PT_YIELD(pt);   //blocked at lineB
     }

     PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, eventB == 1);  //block at lineC
  }
  PT_END(pt)
}
```

After a while, `mythread` can be blocked at "lineA", "lineB", or "lineC".

How could an external function, like `main()` reset `mythread` to be blocked at the beginning "lineA" again.

By running the macro `PT_RESTART(&pt_mythread)`? The compiler doesn't like it. Because my `main()` function isn't inside PT_BEGIN, PT_END block, so the `return` inside that macro is bad, bad.

Or running `PT_INIT(&pt_mythread)` again? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, calling `PT_INIT` from outside the protothread will restart it. If you look at the source for `PT_RESTART`:

```
#define PT_RESTART(pt)              \
  do {                      \
    PT_INIT(pt);                \
    return PT_WAITING;          \
  } while(0)
```

This is exactly what it does, but then also returns (like a yield) out of the thread. As you say it's designed to be called from inside the protothread.

The protothread struct is basically just a number representing where it was in the thread:

```
struct pt {
  lc_t lc; // where lc_t is an unsigned short;
};
```

So the only thing we need to do is reset that number to zero, which is exactly what `PT_INIT` does.